# How does $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!2^{4n}}$ converge to $1/\sqrt2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Series :** $S = 1-\frac{\pi^2}{2!2^4}+\frac{\pi^{4}}{4!2^{8}}-\frac{\pi^{6}}{6!2^{12}}+\cdots.$

**To prove :** $S$ converges, and it coverges to $1/\sqrt2$

**How i attempted :** I could prove $S$ converges with the help of ratio test, as we know the general term for the series $S$ is $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!2^{4n}}$, similarly $a_{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\pi^{2(n+1)}}{(2n+2)!2^{4(n+1)}}$

and so applying ratio test : $$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\pi^{2(n+1)}}{(2n+2)!2^{4(n+1)}}}{\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!2^{4n}}}\right|  \Rightarrow \left| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\pi^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)2^4} \right|\to 0$$
as $n$ tends infinity, so definitely $S$ is converging.

**My problem:** I am not able to prove the other part that is $S$ converges to $1/\sqrt2$, so please help.

Comment: Do you know the power series of $\cos$?

Comment: @DanielFischer well umm yes now i do see a pattern i didn't think of it then, but ok then ?

Comment: Yujie Zha's posted answer is labeled a "HINT", but it's really a pretty thorough summary of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ around $0$, and then set $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$